# What does "java.sql.SQLException: No tables used" mean? Jboss + Hibernate

Tags: java, jdbc

I am using JBoss 5.1 and I get the same error either with MySQL 5 or HSQLDB. Of course I already tried Google, but it seems that I am the only one who gets such an exception. Does anyone know what it means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the MySQL reference, this happens if the query has no *FROM* clause, or has a *FROM DUAL* clause.

Can you post the request on which you're having this error ? Use `<property name="show_sql">true</property>` to log generated SQL in Hibernate.